# Parsing data with more conditions in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have big table of data (50 columns, >50 rows) and I need to parse specific columns first by `&` and then by `:` in column (3,4,5). Problem is, that I do not know, how many times is observed in my data value separated by `&` and `:`. And then in column (9,10) parse by `()`.

The reason for parsing is because I need to filtrate data by its numeric value.

Data are tab delimeter. If the value missing - there is a mark `-`.

Lets see the input tab:

```
Ref Alt GMAF    EUR_MAF ExAC_MAF    Consequence IMPACT  BIOTYPE SIFT    POLYPHEN    Chr DP  Freq    Gen SYMBOL
AC  A   -   -   -   TF_binding_site_variant MODIFIER    -   tolerated(0.51) benign(0.001)   chrM    98  94.9    HOM -
C   CTTTCTT G:0.0004&-:0.4535   -   TTTCTT:0.496&TGTCTT:8.275e-06&TCTCTT:8.275e-06  inframe_insertion   MODERATE    protein_coding  -   -   chr1    109 24.77   HET CDK11A
C   CAT -:0.2622&A:0.2188   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  tolerated(1)    benign(0.002)   chr1    86  36.05   HET CDK11A
A   AG  -:0.4958    G:0.6889    -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  deleterious(0)  probably_damaging(0.996)    chr1    50  32  HET MMEL1
C   CG  -:0.0000    G:1 G:1.000 intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  tolerated(1)    benign(0)   chr1    84  95.24   HOM PLEKHG5
CT  C   T:0.1619    -:0.7724    -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  tolerated(1)    benign(0)   chr1    55  58.18   HET TMEM51
CCTT    C   CTT:0.2766  -:0.8062    -:0.775 intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  -   -   chr1    58  48.28   HET CLCNKB
C   CTCCTG  TCCTG:0.0976    TCCTG:0.0984    -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  -   -   chr1    58  50  HET CLCNKB
AG  A   -:0.1006    -:0.0984    A:1.602e-03&-:0.083 intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  -   -   chr1    88  40.91   HET CLCNKB
```

and required output table:

```
Ref Alt GMAF    GMAF    GMAF    GMAF    EUR_MAF EUR_MAF ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    Consequence IMPACT  BIOTYPE SIFT    SIFT    POLYPHEN    POLYPHEN    Chr DP  Freq    Gen SYMBOL
AC  A   -       -   0.4535  -   -   -   -   -   -   -       TF_binding_site_variant MODIFIER    -   tolerated   0.51    benign  0.001   chrM    98  94.9    HOM -
C   CTTTCTT G   0.0004  A   0.2188  -   -   TTTCTT  0.496   TGTCTT  8.28E-006   TCTCTT  8.28E-006   inframe_insertion   MODERATE    protein_coding  -       -       chr1    109 24.77   HET CDK11A
C   CAT -   0.2622  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  tolerated   1   benign  0.002   chr1    86  36.05   HET CDK11A
A   AG  -   0.4958  -   -   G   0.6889  -   -   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  deleterious 0   probably_damaging   0.996   chr1    50  32  HET MMEL1
C   CG  -   0   -   -   G   1   G   1   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  tolerated   1   benign  0   chr1    84  95.24   HOM PLEKHG5
CT  C   T   0.1619  -   -   -   0.7724  -       -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  tolerated   1   benign  0   chr1    55  58.18   HET TMEM51
CCTT    C   CTT 0.2766  -   -   -   0.8062  -   0.775   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  -       -   -   chr1    58  48.28   HET CLCNKB
C   CTCCTG  TCCTG   0.0976  -   -   TCCTG   0.0984  -       -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  -       -   -   chr1    58  50  HET CLCNKB
AG  A   -   0.1006  -   -   -   0.0984  A   1.60E-003   -   0.083   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding  -       -   -   chr1    88  40.91   HET CLCNKB
```

Solution is not required in awk / sed, but is is preferable. Thank you for any idea.

EDIT READABLE TABLE:

INPUT:

```
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| Ref  | Alt     | GMAF              | EUR_MAF      | ExAC_MAF                                       | Consequence             | IMPACT   | BIOTYPE        | SIFT            | POLYPHEN                 | Chr  | DP  | Freq  | Gen | SYMBOL  |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| AC   | A       | -                 | -            | -                                              | TF_binding_site_variant | MODIFIER | -              | tolerated(0.51) | benign(0.001)            | chrM | 98  | 94.9  | HOM | -       |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CTTTCTT | G:0.0004&-:0.4535 | -            | TTTCTT:0.496&TGTCTT:8.275e-06&TCTCTT:8.275e-06 | inframe_insertion       | MODERATE | protein_coding | -               | -                        | chr1 | 109 | 24.77 | HET | CDK11A  |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CAT     | -:0.2622&A:0.2188 | -            | -                                              | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated(1)    | benign(0.002)            | chr1 | 86  | 36.05 | HET | CDK11A  |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| A    | AG      | -:0.4958          | G:0.6889     | -                                              | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | deleterious(0)  | probably_damaging(0.996) | chr1 | 50  | 32    | HET | MMEL1   |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CG      | -:0.0000          | G:1          | G:1.000                                        | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated(1)    | benign(0)                | chr1 | 84  | 95.24 | HOM | PLEKHG5 |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| CT   | C       | T:0.1619          | -:0.7724     | -                                              | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated(1)    | benign(0)                | chr1 | 55  | 58.18 | HET | TMEM51  |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| CCTT | C       | CTT:0.2766        | -:0.8062     | -:0.775                                        | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -               | -                        | chr1 | 58  | 48.28 | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CTCCTG  | TCCTG:0.0976      | TCCTG:0.0984 | -                                              | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -               | -                        | chr1 | 58  | 50    | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| AG   | A       | -:0.1006          | -:0.0984     | A:1.602e-03&-:0.083                            | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -               | -                        | chr1 | 88  | 40.91 | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
```

OTPUT:

```
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| Ref  | Alt     | GMAF  | GMAF   | GMAF | GMAF   | EUR_MAF | EUR_MAF | ExAC_MAF | ExAC_MAF  | ExAC_MAF | ExAC_MAF  | ExAC_MAF | ExAC_MAF  | Consequence             | IMPACT   | BIOTYPE        | SIFT        | SIFT | POLYPHEN          | POLYPHEN | Chr  | DP  | Freq  | Gen | SYMBOL  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| AC   | A       | -     |        | -    | 0.4535 | -       | -       | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        |           | TF_binding_site_variant | MODIFIER | -              | tolerated   | 0.51 | benign            | 0.001    | chrM | 98  | 94.9  | HOM | -       |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CTTTCTT | G     | 0.0004 | A    | 0.2188 | -       | -       | TTTCTT   | 0.496     | TGTCTT   | 8.28E-006 | TCTCTT   | 8.28E-006 | inframe_insertion       | MODERATE | protein_coding | -           |      | -                 |          | chr1 | 109 | 24.77 | HET | CDK11A  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CAT     | -     | 0.2622 | -    | -      | -       | -       | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated   | 1    | benign            | 0.002    | chr1 | 86  | 36.05 | HET | CDK11A  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| A    | AG      | -     | 0.4958 | -    | -      | G       | 0.6889  | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | deleterious | 0    | probably_damaging | 0.996    | chr1 | 50  | 32    | HET | MMEL1   |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CG      | -     | 0      | -    | -      | G       | 1       | G        | 1         | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated   | 1    | benign            | 0        | chr1 | 84  | 95.24 | HOM | PLEKHG5 |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| CT   | C       | T     | 0.1619 | -    | -      | -       | 0.7724  | -        |           | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated   | 1    | benign            | 0        | chr1 | 55  | 58.18 | HET | TMEM51  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| CCTT | C       | CTT   | 0.2766 | -    | -      | -       | 0.8062  | -        | 0.775     | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -           |      | -                 | -        | chr1 | 58  | 48.28 | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CTCCTG  | TCCTG | 0.0976 | -    | -      | TCCTG   | 0.0984  | -        |           | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -           |      | -                 | -        | chr1 | 58  | 50    | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| AG   | A       | -     | 0.1006 | -    | -      | -       | 0.0984  | A        | 1.60E-003 | -        | 0.083     | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -           |      | -                 | -        | chr1 | 88  | 40.91 | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
```

My try was to use something like this (according my previous question):

```
awk -F'[ \t:&]+' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

but this does not parse document exact my criteria.

Comment: Please use this tool to make readable tables: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Comment: Can't you come up with, say, a 4x4 table that demonstrates your problem rather than one that scrolls off the side of the page? You'd probably get a lot more people interested in reading it if it was minimal (as in [mcve]).

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `gawk`

```
awk '
    BEGIN{OFS="\t"; split("3 4 5 9 10",a)}
    NR==FNR{
        for(i in a){
            n=split($a[i], v, /[:&(]/);
            if(n>max[a[i]]) max[a[i]]=n
        }
        next
    }
    {
        for(i in max){
            s=""
            if(FNR==1) for(j=1; j<=max[i]; ++j) s = s OFS $i
            else{
                gsub(")","",$i)
                n=split($i, v, /[:&(]/)
                for(j=1; j<=max[i]; ++j){
                    if(j<=n) s = s OFS v[j]
                    else s = s OFS "-"
                }
            }
            $i = s
        }
        print
    }' file{,}
```

you get,

```
Ref Alt     GMAF    GMAF    GMAF    GMAF        EUR_MAF EUR_MAF     ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    ExAC_MAF    Consequence IMPACT  BIOTYPE     SIFT    SIFT        POLYPHEN    POLYPHEN    Chr DP  Freq    Gen SYMBOL
AC  A       -   -   -   -       -   -       -   -   -   -   -   -   TF_binding_site_variant MODIFIER    -       tolerated   0.51        benign  0.001   chrM    98  94.9    HOM -
C   CTTTCTT     G   0.0004  -   0.4535      -   -       TTTCTT  0.496   TGTCTT  8.275e-06   TCTCTT  8.275e-06   inframe_insertion   MODERATE    protein_coding      -   -       -   -   chr1    109 24.77   HET CDK11A
C   CAT     -   0.2622  A   0.2188      -   -       -   -   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding      tolerated   1       benign  0.002   chr1    86  36.05   HET CDK11A
A   AG      -   0.4958  -   -       G   0.6889      -   -   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding      deleterious 0       probably_damaging   0.996   chr1    50  32  HET MMEL1
C   CG      -   0.0000  -   -       G   1       G   1.000   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding      tolerated   1       benign  0   chr1    84  95.24   HOM PLEKHG5
CT  C       T   0.1619  -   -       -   0.7724      -   -   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding      tolerated   1       benign  0   chr1    55  58.18   HET TMEM51
CCTT    C       CTT 0.2766  -   -       -   0.8062      -   0.775   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding      -   -       -   -   chr1    58  48.28   HET CLCNKB
C   CTCCTG      TCCTG   0.0976  -   -       TCCTG   0.0984      -   -   -   -   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding      -   -       -   -   chr1    58  50  HET CLCNKB
AG  A       -   0.1006  -   -       -   0.0984      A   1.602e-03   -   0.083   -   -   intron_variant  MODIFIER    protein_coding      -   -       -   -   chr1    88  40.91   HET CLCNKB
```

```
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| Ref  | Alt     | GMAF  | GMAF   | GMAF | GMAF   | EUR_MAF | EUR_MAF | ExAC_MAF | ExAC_MAF  | ExAC_MAF | ExAC_MAF  | ExAC_MAF | ExAC_MAF  | Consequence             | IMPACT   | BIOTYPE        | SIFT        | SIFT | POLYPHEN          | POLYPHEN | Chr  | DP  | Freq  | Gen | SYMBOL  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| AC   | A       | -     | -      | -    | -      | -       | -       | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        | -         | TF_binding_site_variant | MODIFIER | -              | tolerated   | 0.51 | benign            | 0.001    | chrM | 98  | 94.9  | HOM | -       |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CTTTCTT | G     | 0.0004 | -    | 0.4535 | -       | -       | TTTCTT   | 0.496     | TGTCTT   | 8.275e-06 | TCTCTT   | 8.275e-06 | inframe_insertion       | MODERATE | protein_coding | -           | -    | -                 | -        | chr1 | 109 | 24.77 | HET | CDK11A  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CAT     | -     | 0.2622 | A    | 0.2188 | -       | -       | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated   | 1    | benign            | 0.002    | chr1 | 86  | 36.05 | HET | CDK11A  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| A    | AG      | -     | 0.4958 | -    | -      | G       | 0.6889  | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | deleterious | 0    | probably_damaging | 0.996    | chr1 | 50  | 32    | HET | MMEL1   |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CG      | -     | 0.0000 | -    | -      | G       | 1       | G        | 1.000     | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated   | 1    | benign            | 0        | chr1 | 84  | 95.24 | HOM | PLEKHG5 |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| CT   | C       | T     | 0.1619 | -    | -      | -       | 0.7724  | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | tolerated   | 1    | benign            | 0        | chr1 | 55  | 58.18 | HET | TMEM51  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| CCTT | C       | CTT   | 0.2766 | -    | -      | -       | 0.8062  | -        | 0.775     | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -           | -    | -                 | -        | chr1 | 58  | 48.28 | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| C    | CTCCTG  | TCCTG | 0.0976 | -    | -      | TCCTG   | 0.0984  | -        | -         | -        | -         | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -           | -    | -                 | -        | chr1 | 58  | 50    | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
| AG   | A       | -     | 0.1006 | -    | -      | -       | 0.0984  | A        | 1.602e-03 | -        | 0.083     | -        | -         | intron_variant          | MODIFIER | protein_coding | -           | -    | -                 | -        | chr1 | 88  | 40.91 | HET | CLCNKB  |
+------+---------+-------+--------+------+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------+-------------------+----------+------+-----+-------+-----+---------+
```